# Switched from 2.79 to 2.81 Undo command works in a weird way now, how to make it behave exactly like it used to in 2.79?

Tags: customization

From other post people suggest checking/unchecking "global undo"  in settings but that's not it. It's still doesn't work as it used to.

Comment: What exactly doesn't work properly, can you give an example?